# c++ closure creation

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, closures, c++14

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  // Block 1
  {
    auto inc = []() { int i = 0; return [&]() { return i++; }; }();
    std::vector<int> v(10, 10);
    std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), inc);
    for (auto i : v) std::cout << i << std::endl;
  }

  // Block 2
  {
    auto inc = []() { int i = 0; return [&]() { return i++; }; };
    std::vector<int> v(10, 10);
    std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), inc());
    for (auto i : v) std::cout << i << std::endl;
  }
}
```

I am not sure why these two blocks produce different results.

```
Block 1: 32767 ... 32776
Block 2: 0 ... 10
```

And for `std::generate` the generator(`inc`) is passed by value, so I believe it should be fine, right?

I am running OS X.

Thanks,

---

**Note that the results from above code are undefined, see below.**

Comment: Cannot reproduce, gcc v5.1.0 generates the same output in both cases

Comment: I am compiling with clang version 3.6.2.

Comment: Nevermind, it is UB, so particular output is irrelevant

Comment: Why somebody downvoted it? It is rare case when OP followed rules precisely and created [mcve]. This is valid question no matter if code has UB or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I am not sure why these two blocks produce different results.

Both are undefined behavior, so the question is moot. In either case, we have a lambda like:

```
auto f = []() { int i = 0; return [&]() { return i++; }; };
```

And `f()` returns a lambda that has a dangling reference: `i` is destroyed at the end of the call to `f`. It's immaterial *when* that dangling reference happens - whether it happens long before the `generate()` call or into the `generate()` call.

If you want to make a generating counter with a lambda, the direct way is to make the lambda mutable and use init-capture:

```
auto inc = [i=0]() mutable { return i++; };
```

The `mutable` is required because lambdas are `const` by default, and we need to directly modify the member `i`.

---

The above is C++14 (due to the generalized init-capture). We could make this work in C++11 by simply changing the nested-lambda structure from the inner lambda capturing by reference to capturing by value:

```
auto inc = []{ int i = 0; return [=]() mutable { return i++; }; }();
//                               ~~~   ~~~~~~~
```

That's... kind of obnoxious, but it works?

Comment: Does [i=0] require c++14?

Comment: @Slava Yes, added a way to fix OP's original nested-lambda example to still work in C++11.

Comment: Thanks, since `i` is a local temporary object inside the `operator()` if you think the lambda like a `struct`. Thus what the returned lambda captures is an invalid reference to local variable. That's why both cases are UB. At first I thought it would behave like real closures.

Comment: Is there any reason why the "*but it works?*" part exists? I can't seem to think why it shouldn't. Also, why not just capture only `i`?

Comment: @Rakete1111 I don't understand any of the questions. The "but it works" is a rhetorical counterpoint to "kind of obnoxious"